# Switch-SQLAvailability error during DB Restore in AlwaysON Group

Tags: sql-server-2014, restore, availability-groups, powershell, failover

Can anyone share your inputs on below and how to fix the issue and possible causes of failure?

I am trying to restore a DB using PS script and at one step it is failing during the role change test and during failover.

All Databases are Synchronized and BCP is Synchronizing and alwayson AG is in green and Healthy.

But I am still facing the below issue.

[image]

Verified the SQL Server logs and can see below point:

> A connection timeout has occurred while attempting to establish a
>   connection to availability replica '' with id
>   [xxxxxxxx]. Either a networking or
>   firewall issue exists, or the endpoint address provided for the
>   replica is not the database mirroring endpoint of the host server
>   instance.

Comment: When you restore the database, are you adding it to the Availability Group before attempting failover? If so, are you also restoring the DB on the secondary replicas and joining it to the AG on them as well?

Comment: Yes @HandyD , that is right .  Mine is a 3 Replica AG . 2 Synchronized and BCP Synchronizing.

Comment: When you are testing failover, are you failing over to a synchronous or asynchronous replica?

Comment: Based on your error the path does not look correct: `SQLSERVER:\SQL\$SecondaryReplica$SecDefault\` Is that correct? If this is a named instance or default that path is done as `SQLSERVER:\SQL\$SecondarReplica\$InstanceName\` (named instance) or `SQLSERVER:\SQL\$SecondarReplica\DEFAULT\...` (default instance).

Comment: Thank you Shawn and HandyD , I figured out the issue. Issue is with Sleep time in the code . It is set for 10 seconds , during this time the failover is not able to 100% complete . After increasing the sleep time to 40 it got processed successfully. Thanks for your time .